# Calculate the perimeter and area of intersecting rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, tree, intervals

I searched a lot, but I didn't find a good answer that works for this case.
We have some rectangles that are horizontal or vertical. They can be placed on the page randomly. They can overlap or have a common edge or be separate from each other.
I want to find an algorithm with O(nlogn) that can find perimeter and area of these rectangles.
These pictures may make the problem clear.

[image]

I think that interval trees might help, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: My guess would be perimeter :)

Comment: I think you can only get an O(n^2) as the best outcome, as you have to check for intersections between one rectangle and all other rectangles, then calculate an the area of the intersection and the perimeters of each so that you don't add it twice to the sum. But basically, you need all the points of rectangle intersection first, so that you know where to move next in your calculation.

Comment: heh! yeah perimeter.searching dictionary for finding a good word some times failed. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done by a *sweep-line* algorithm.

We'll sweep an imaginary line from left to right. 
We'll notice the way the intersection between the line and the set of rectangles represents a set of intervals, and that it changes when we encounter a left or right edge of a rectangle.

Let's say that the intersection doesn't change between x coordinates **x1** and **x2**.
Then, if the length of the intersection after **x1** was **L**, the line would have swept an area equal to (**x2** - **x1**) * **L**, by sweeping from **x1** to **x2**.

For example, you can look at **x1** as the left blue line, and **x1** as the right blue line on the following picture (that I stole from you and modified a bit :)):
[image]

It should be clear that the intersection of our *sweep-line* doesn't change between those points. However, the blue intersection is quite different from the red one.

We'll need a data structure with these operations:

```
insert_interval(y1, y2); 
get_total_length();
```

Those are easily implemented with a *segment tree*, so I won't go into details now.

Now, the algorithm would go like this:

1. Take all the vertical segments and sort them by their x coordinates.
2. For each relevant x coordinate (only the ones appearing as edges of rectangles are important):

   - Let x1 be the previous relevant x coordinate.
   - Let x2 be the current relevant x coordinate.
   - Let L be the length given by our data structure.
   - Add (x2 - x1) * L to the total area sum.
   - Remove all the *right* edges with x = x2 segments from the data structure.
   - Add all the *left* edges with x = x2 segments to the data structure.

By *left* and *right* I mean the sides of a rectangle.

This idea was given only for computing the area, however, you may modify it to compute the perimeter. Basically you'll want to know the difference between the lengths of the intersection before and after it changes at some x coordinate.

The complexity of the algorithm is O(N log N) (although it depends on the range of values you might get as input, this is easily dealt with).

You can find more information on the broad topic of *sweep-line* algorithms on [TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lineSweep).

You can read about various ways to use the *segment tree* on the [PEG judge wiki](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Segment_tree).

Here's my (really old) implementation of the algorithm as a solution to the [SPOJ problem NKMARS](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NKMARS/): [implementation](http://pastebin.com/RW2fyrZk).

Comment: thanks a lot.what is time complexity of this algorithm? i think it is not O(nlogn).yeah?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've edited the answer (and also added a link to my old implementation).

Answer (score 0):

The following is O(N2) solution.

```
int area = 0;
FOR(triange=0->N)
{
    Area = area trianlges[triangle];
    FOR(int j = triangle+1 -> N)
    {
        area-= inter(triangle , j)
    }
}
return area;

int inter(tri a,tri b)
{
    if ( ( min(a.highY ,b.highY) > max(a.lowerY, b.lowerY) ) && ( min(a.highX ,b.highX) > max(a.lowerX, b.lowerX) ) )
    return ( min(a.highY ,b.highY) - max(a.lowerY, b.lowerY) ) * ( min(a.highX ,b.highX) - max(a.lowerX, b.lowerX) )

    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: this does not work if there are more than two rectangles intersecting at a same point.