# How to find the border length created from a conglomeration of various 2D rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

You are given a set of rectangles and you are asked to determine the length of the perimeter of the complex polygon formed by the silhouette of the overlapping rectangles.

Comment: Am I correct to assume all the rectangles form one shape only?

Comment: Yes, it can be reduced to that case.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the perimeter of a complex polygon, and how to combine two of them to get one?

Comment: I can combine two poligons by finding intersections and discarding the points inside poligon. To find the perimeter is trivial. Can we use the fact that we deal with rectangle and optimize it?

Comment: If this is an *optimization* problem, you should say so.

Comment: How many rectangles ?

Comment: It was an interview question. Best performance you can is required.

Comment: Grrr, this kind of information must be provided in the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book "Computational Geometry" of Preparata and Shamos the 8th chapter is devoted to rectangles union problems. The problem of union perimeter is solved with sweep line algorithm  ([link one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) [link two](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/)) and segment tree in O(NLogN) time

[Addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505668/calculate-the-perimeter-and-area-of-intersecting-rectangles)

Answer (score 0):

- We start with the positions (of all 4 points) of each of the various smaller overlapping rectangles.
- We construct the new polygon by walking through the corner points of the various rectangles.
- We find the most outlying points (farthest North/South/East/West) encountered for any given row or column of the matrix, storing these in a separate array.
- Once we have gathered all the points for our new polygon, we sort its points in a clockwise order around the center of the grid (if not already sorted).
- We measure its perimeter by measuring the distance of each line (between each set of consecutive points) on its surface and adding it to the total.

> ```
>  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  .  .  *  x  x  *  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  .  .  x  .  .  x  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  .  .  x  .  .  x  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  *  z  *  z  .  x  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  z  .  x  z  .  x  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  z  .  x  z  .  x  .  .  .  .
>  .  *  *  y  y  y  y  *  y  y  *  .
>  .  y  z  .  x  z  .  x  .  .  y  .
>  .  *  *  y  y  y  y  *  y  y  *  .
>  .  .  z  .  x  z  .  x  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  z  .  x  *  x  *  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  z  .  .  z  .  .  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  *  z  z  *  .  .  .  .  .  .
>  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
> ```

In the diagram above, we have rectangles x, y, and z.  Asterisks the are outlying corners of our new polygon.

Comment: Walking through the grid will take too much time. Think about a rectangle with 10^7 height or width.

Answer (score 0):

Are the rectangles axis-aligned? If so, you can try this. Sort starts and ends along one axis (let's say x), then maintain a list of consecutive intervals - points, sorted by y, with each interval having an integer 'winding number' (initially ymin..ymax, 0). Then when you process the next edge along x, you find what existing intervals it overlaps with, splitting the ones on the ends, and update (++ for front edges, -- for back edges) their winding numbers. For instance:

```
 0000111111122222111000
+000++++++++++000000000
=0001222222233222111000
    1                   (perimeter update)
```

For opening eges, add new intervals with winding number 1 to the perimeter. For closing - with 0. For efficiency, you can also merge intervals with identical winding numbers.

Then do the same for y.

Comment: Yes, rectangles are axis-aligned. The problem is that x can be more than 10^7 so calculating ymin,ymax for each takes too much time.

Comment: absolute dimensions shouldn't matter, it's pure interval arithmetic. it's only as complex as the total number of points. i.e. the intervals are stored not as 'pixels', but as lists of bounds